# Recovery Partition ID cannot be set on primary partition

Tags: windows, recovery

As part of extending the size of the volume on Azure VM, i need to re-create Recovery Partition. I am following this guide, [here](http://woshub.com/extend-volume-blocked-by-windows-recovery-partition/).
I am attempting to set the set id="de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac" for the primary partition intended to be used as recovery partition.  I get the error:

```
The specified type is not in the correct format.
For more information on the command type: HELP SET
```

The volume is not GPT, it appears, so unsure how to make Win 10 to recognize it.  Any thoughts are welcome here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know I am late but just for anyone who ends up here by a google search if your disk is using MBR not GPT then you need to set the id to "27" instead of "de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac" so it should look like this `set id=27`

Source: https://foxdeploy.com/2017/03/13/solved-windows-10-reset-there-was-a-problem-resetting-your-pc/

https://superuser.com/questions/1108243/setting-winre-windows-recovery-environment-flag-on-partitions

Comment: I don't quite get why this was question was closed, but @Mostafa, your answer fixed a problem that had me completely roadblocked for almost an hour.  Thanks!!

Comment: Probably because this is a superuser question instead of Stack Overflow type of question.